# Tag Cleanup, *core*

Tags: discussion, retag-request

While searching for some information related to Windows Server Core, I went to the tag search and searched for `core`.

There are many takes which seem to overlap related to multi-core processors.  [multi-core](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/multi-core) seems to have the most inertia.

- [multi-core](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/multi-core) × 62
- [core](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/core) × 15
- [cores](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cores) × 18
- [multicore](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/multicore) × 6
- [core2-duo](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/core2-duo) × 4
- [quad-core](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/quad-core) × 4

Comment: Wow, "core" is a mess of cpu core, core dumps and software with core in the name... cores and multicore all seem like they should get merged into multi-core with a synonym configured.

Comment: Should be burninated...and blacklisted. And cast into the fiery depths of hell...

Comment: In a perfect world, [tag:smp] and [tag:numa] should suffice

Answer (score 4):

I fixed up the obvious stuff... [core](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/core) needs to be gone through manually.

Answer (score 3):

[core](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/core) and [core2-duo](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/core2-duo) have been purged of questions.  The others have been merged into [multi-core](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/multi-core), presumably by Chris S.